# reCAPTCHA doesn't work in Twitter Bootstrap dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a reCAPTCHA in Twitter Bootstrap dialog. I found that it doesn't work. Nothing was shown in the dialog.

Here are my codes:
in `body`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="recaptchaModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Enter the text below to continue</h4>
                    </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" id="recaptcha_div">
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submitForm()">Continue</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

at the button of body:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

in `JavaScript` file
...

```
function buttonAction() {
    showRecaptcha();
    $('#recaptchaModel').modal();
};
function showRecaptcha(){
                Recaptcha.create("my key(I am sure that I put the correct key", 'recaptcha_div', {
                    theme: "red",
                    callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field});
            };
```

Here is the result
[image: It only shows the header and footer]

Can anyone help me to fix my code? Thanks!

Comment: Listen for the `shown.bs.modal` event and initialize the caption then instead.

Comment: Example code please :)

Comment: Sorry, I got it fixed. I shouldn't test my webpage directly using browser :\